# OracleTruncateException

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I get an OracleTruncateException when selection some data from the database.

Couldn't find any explanation on it other then "The OracleTruncateException class represents an exception that is thrown when truncation in an ODP.NET Type class occurs"

What is it, and how can I avoid/cope with it?

Comment: Can you tell us the datatypes of the selections being made ?

Comment: Found the problem.

I was passing parameter to the query of type decimal and the value that was sent exceeded the precision and scale.
Once I set them to the correct value - or zero - it was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

I was passing parameter to the query of type decimal and the value that was sent exceeded the precision and scale

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the table you select from has a column with a `blob`, `clob` or `long` column-type?